# angular interceptor trying to make a interceptor which queue the request of max request 10

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, angular-http-interceptors

```
# import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
# import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
# import { Observable, interval } from 'rxjs';
# import { of } from 'rxjs/internal/observable/of';
# import { map } from 'rxjs/internal/operators/map';
# import { finalize, last, mapTo, mergeMap, takeWhile } from 'rxjs/operators';
# export const MAX_REQUESTS = 10;
# # @Injectable()
# export class SmartCountInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
# private activeRequests = 0;
# intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
# Check if the maximum number of active requests has been reached
# if (this.activeRequests >= MAX_REQUESTS) {
# Wait for ongoing requests to complete before processing the new request
# return this.waitForActiveRequests().pipe(
# mergeMap(() => {
# Clone the request to prevent modification
# const clonedReq = req.clone();
# Increment the count of active requests
# this.activeRequests++;
# Handle the request
# return next.handle(clonedReq).pipe(
# finalize(() => {
# Decrement the count of active requests when the request completes
# this.activeRequests--;
# #             })
# #           );
# #         })
# #       );
# else {
# Clone the request to prevent modification
# const clonedReq = req.clone();
# Increment the count of active requests
# this.activeRequests++;
# Handle the request
# return next.handle(clonedReq).pipe(
# finalize(() => {
# Decrement the count of active requests when the request completes
# this.activeRequests--;
# #         }),
# mergeMap(event => {
# Wait for ongoing requests to complete before emitting the event
# return this.waitForActiveRequests().pipe(map(() => event));
# #         })
# #       );
# #     }
# #   }
# private waitForActiveRequests(): Observable<void> {
# if (this.activeRequests < MAX_REQUESTS) {
# If the maximum number of active requests has not been reached, return an empty observable
# return of(null);
# else {
# Otherwise, wait for all active requests to complete
# return interval(100).pipe(
# takeWhile(() => this.activeRequests > MAX_REQUESTS),
# last(),
# mapTo(null)
# #       );
# #     }
# #   }
# # }
```

This is my interceptor in which all the request are been intercepted, but few requests show error Empty error 'no elements in sequence'. I tried removing `last()` and used take 1 but still the issue persists.

I need to take care whatever b the request number it will first send 10 request at  time and if response comes of any one or two accordingly the active request will be pushed

Comment: Please improve the formatting of your question, it's very hard to read. Remove all the hashtags from the code. Users should be able to copy and paste the code to try it out. Also it would be good to format the code so it's better readable. Additionally, please don't put your description into a H1 heading, the font size is way too big. It should be just a regular paragraph. (Note: I partially fixed the issues by an edit)

Comment: stack overflow is not allowing me to do so as mesg is too lomg